# Conditionally changing the color of a paramater word

Tags: java, android

I have a string called ishacked that should be red if the boolean hacked returns true and green if it returns false.

I want to place it inside a textview like this:

```
dynamicTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display, ishacked));
```

the string text is in strings.xml:

```
<string name="display">Current application activation status:\n %1$s</string>
```

i've tried an implemnation with `Spannablestring` like this (this code is placed **before** the textview setText):

```
if (hacked) {
        ishacked = "Not active --> invalid license!";
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        SpannableString redSpannable = new SpannableString(ishacked);
        redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ishacked.length(), 0);
        builder.append(redSpannable);
    } else {
        ishacked = "Active (Genuine license)";
        SpannableStringBuilder builder2 = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        SpannableString redSpannable = new SpannableString(ishacked);
        redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, ishacked.length(), 0);
        builder2.append(redSpannable);
    }
```

But actually the text color doesn't apply. Can anyone tell me why or what i've done wrong?

the ouptut text should be something like this

if hacked returns true:

```
Current application activation status: Not active --> invalid license!
```

"Not active --> invalid license!" should be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did. I hope it will be helpful.

```
    String firstString = "Current applications activation status:\n";
    String ishacked = "Not active --> invalid license!";
    String totalString = "Current applications activation status:\n Not active --> invalid license!";




    Spannable sptext = new SpannableString(totalString);
    sptext.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)),String.valueOf(firstString).length(),totalString.length(), 0);
    textView.setText(sptext);
```

[image]

Comment: tried to implement your code like this to try: `ishacked = "Not active --> invalid license!";
            Spannable redSpannable = new SpannableString(ishacked);
            redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ishacked.length(), 0);
            dynamicTextView.setText("Current applications activation status:\n "+redSpannable+"");` still no luck...

Comment: Try this one above

Comment: Please don't add [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). OP and future users will not be able to copy or search this code. The code should be in the answer as text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little confused by what you're trying to accomplish, but normally to change the color of text that you're displaying just requires setting the text color attribute on the text view.

```
dynamicTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
```

Where `R.color.red` is your color resource for being hacked. Then you'd just do same thing for when you want it to be green.

Comment: thanks, but this will make the whole TexTview to be red or green. i want to modify the color of just the ishacked string wich will be next to rest of the display string in the textview. i wrote the output example now in the question

Comment: You could just use two separate text views that are right next to each other (to make it look like one display).

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the part where you set the text

```
dynamicTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.display) +  builder);
```

or

```
dynamicTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.display) +  builder2);
```

But instead **you're setting the string without span applied**

Comment: Did you try putting builder directly to your edittext?

Answer (score 0):

try this, the following worked fine for me on TextView

txtView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));